# How would you format an Auth/OAuth header like this a Python dict?

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, xauth

I'm using python-requests to get an access_token from Twitter using xAuth and their private keys. Currently, an issue is that I don't know how to format this header:

> Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="key_here",oauth_nonce="72393267",oauth_signature="signature_here",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1383672378",oauth_version="1.0"

Currently I'm formatting it as follows:

> {'Authorization': 'OAuth',
>            'oauth_consumer_key': 'dWW6V8isvSGRL4qbElrGw',
>            'oauth_nonce': params['oauth_nonce'],
>            'oauth_signature': '',
>            'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
>            'oauth_timestamp': params['oauth_timestamp'],
>            'oauth_version': '1.0'
>            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, I just needed to put it in a string (keep in mind the **ORDER IS EVERYTHING**, if the keys/values are out of order then it won't work). The header looks like the following

> OAuth oauth_consumer_key="consumer_key", oauth_nonce="61959852", oauth_signature="signature", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1383694192", oauth_version="1.0"

My very simple code to do this is as follows:

```
def auth_header(creds, http_session):
    auth = 'OAuth ' + 'oauth_consumer_key=\"' + creds['oauth_consumer_key']
    auth = auth + '\",oauth_nonce=\"' + creds['oauth_nonce']
    auth = auth + '\",oauth_signature=\"' + creds['oauth_signature']
    auth = auth + '\",oauth_signature_method=\"' + creds['oauth_signature_method']
    auth = auth + '\",oauth_timestamp=\"' + creds['oauth_timestamp']
    auth = auth + '\",oauth_version=\"' + creds['oauth_version'] + '\"'
    http_session.headers['Authorization'] = auth
```